# Using R to conduct stepwise logistic regression based on p critical

Tags: logistic-regression

The R function step() performs stepwise regression based on AIC critical, but how can I conduct stepwise logistic regression based on pvaule critical?

I haved searched on github, however, there were no effective way to solve my problems.